# nested traversing with in DOM query list in angular

Tags: angular, typescript, angular5

Hi While i was developing a page i came through a requirement which has same level parent checkbox and each parent has their children which are also check boxes. So i need when parent is checked then their respective children should also get checked and if i uncheck then uncheck should happen.
Heres my html & component file. all is working fine but when i m clicking on children checkbox of one parent and then clicking on different parent then its getting messed up. Any help would be appreciated !!

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Input, OnInit, OnDestroy, ViewChildren, ViewChild, ElementRef, QueryList } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  name = 'Angular';
    @ViewChildren('fundMenu') public fundMenu: QueryList<any>;
  @ViewChildren('accountMenu') public accountMenu: ElementRef;
  @ViewChild('allchkbox') public allchkbox: ElementRef;
  fun = false;
  selectToggle = false;
  public rorList = [{ key: 'RET', arr: 
  [{performanceType:[{timePeriod:"aa"}]},
  {performanceType:[{timePeriod:"aa"}]},
  {performanceType:[{timePeriod:"aa"}]}] },
  { key: 'NR', arr: [{performanceType:[{timePeriod:"aa"}]}] }];


   public checkAllAccount(account: any, selectToggle: any, val: any):void {
    if(val === 'ALL') {
    //this.accountMenu = this.selectAllParentCheckBox(this.accountMenu, false, this.allchkbox);
   // this.fundMenu = this.selectAllParentCheckBox(this.fundMenu, false, this.allchkbox);
    } else {
      console.log(this.fundMenu);
      console.log(this.accountMenu);
      this.fundMenu = this.selectAllCheckBox(this.fundMenu,false,val);
    }
  }
  
  public fund(){
    this.fun = true;
  }
   public selectAllCheckBox(checkbox: any, selectToggle: boolean, val : any): any {
    // alert(this.fun);
 //   this.selectToggle = !this.selectToggle;
   // alert(selectToggle);
    //this.accountMenu.first.nativeElement
    checkbox.forEach((chkbox: ElementRef, ind: number) => { 
        if(this.fun === true && ind === 0) {
          //alert(chkbox.nativeElement.checked);
          
          this.selectToggle = chkbox.nativeElement.checked;
          //alert(this.selectToggle);
        }
      //  alert(chkbox.nativeElement.checked);
        if(chkbox.nativeElement.value === val) {
         // chkbox.nativeElement.checked = !this.selectToggle;
        if(this.fun === true)
          chkbox.nativeElement.checked = !this.selectToggle ;
          else
         chkbox.nativeElement.checked= !chkbox.nativeElement.checked;
        }
    });
    this.fun = false;
    return checkbox;
  }
}
```

```html
<hello name="{{ name }}"></hello>
<p>
 Start editing to see some magic happen :)
</p>
<div id=''>
 <div id='' class="" *ngFor='let item of rorList;let i =index'>
  <div>
   <div>
    <div>
     <div>
      <div>
       <span>{{item.key}}</span>
                          <input (click)="checkAllAccount(item.key,i,item.key)" #accountMenu value={{item.key}} type="checkbox">      
                        </div>
                    
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div  *ngFor='let value of item.arr,let i =index'>
              <div  *ngFor='let rorItem of value.performanceType,let i =index'>
                <div >
                    <div>
                        <input (click)='fund(item.key)' #fundMenu value={{item.key}} type="checkbox">
                       
                      </div>
                  
  
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
```

[image]

Comment: Added the image for look like overview

Comment: OMG why do you need all the extra divs :)

Comment: You've got a property `public fundMenu: QueryList<any>` which will be populated with elements, then later you assign something else to it with `this.fundMenu = this.selectAllCheckBox...`. Why are you reassigning it?

Answer (score 0):

You seem to overwrite the `i` variable in your template. First you have:

```
<div id='' class="" *ngFor='let item of rorList;let i =index'>
<input (click)="checkAllAccount(item.key,i,item.key)" #accountMenu value={{item.key}} type="checkbox">
```

(Btw. please use double quotes in the template for attributes.)

Then later you have:

```
<div  *ngFor='let value of item.arr,let i =index'>
  <div  *ngFor='let rorItem of value.performanceType,let i =index'>
```

So I would say your `i` is getting mixed up and that's why you have problematic state.